# Linq: GetElementAt() equivalent for retrieving multiple items?

Tags: linq, range

I have an collection of iQueryable objects. 
Looking through intellisense i see 'GetElementAt(int)' but what i actually want to do is return multiple elements - so something like
GetElementAt(int startindex, int count) GetElementAt(int startindex, int endIndex).

I cant seem to see this. Any ideas?

The only other thing i can think of is to iterate for the number of items i want using 
GetElementAt() each time e.g.

```
for (int i = 20;i<40;i++)
   PrintName(MyList.GetElementAt(i));
```

Which seems to defeat the point abit.

Comment: Here is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287340/net-equivalent-of-javas-list-sublist/1287409#1287409

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like:

```
myList.Skip(startIndex).Take(count);
```

Comment: Don't you just love LINQ? ;-)